# Unwanted VS2015 compiler header warning information

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

I've written an autonomous application that compiles C and C++ code students send me and sends the results back to them.  Since these are beginning students I don't want to overwhelm them with a vast amount of information they won't even understand.  One of the compilers I'm using is the VS2015 compiler from the command line with the following options:

`/MT /GS /O2 /W4 /nologo /EHsc /analyze- /errorReport:none /wd4001 /wd4210 /wd4701 /wd4706 /wd4996 /wd4554 /wd4512 /wd4716`

A improperly-written code statement in one of the .cpp files I received is as follows, where operand2 has type ifstream.  I expect and do get a compiler error on it:

```
cerr << "Couldn't open file: " << operand2 << '\n';
```

However, what I get is much more than I want, as follows:

```
C2A8E1_OpenFiles.cpp(47): error C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\ostream(497): note: could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\ostream(477): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(const void *)'
Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\ostream(457): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long double)'
...and on and on and on...
```

It not only is telling me what is wrong with my file but is also commenting on things I don't care anything about at this point and which will only confuse my students.  With the Intel compiler I only get the following, which is sufficient for the course and is all I want:

```
C2A8E1_OpenFiles.cpp(47): error: no operator "<<" matches these operands
   operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << std::ifstream
   cerr << "Couldn't open file: " << arrayPtr[ifstreamIndex] << '\n';
```

The Intel compiler options are set to the following, and they specify an even higher warning level than for the Microsoft compiler:

```
/MT /GS /O2 /W5 /Za /nologo /EHsc /analyze- /errorReport:none /J /Wcheck /Wport /Qeffc++ /Qdiag-error-limit:10 /Qlong-double /Qms0 /wd4001 /wd4210 /wd4701 /wd4706 /wd4996 /wd4554 /wd4512 /wd4716 /wd1418 /wd2015 /wd2013 /wd1786 /wd1419 /wd981 /wd991 /wd2012 /wd1572 /wd9 /wd187
```

I chose the W4 warning level for Visual Studio simply to get the the most thorough checking I could get but even when I reduce it down to W2 I still get all the unwanted clutter.  Is there a way around this issue?  It is impractical for me to use pragmas or otherwise modify the existing code since all of the files I'm compiling have been pre-written before I get them.

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: I guess just using the Intel compiler isn't an option?

Comment: This is a C++ [FAQ item](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-error-msgs). The FAQ recommends using **[Stlfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html)**. It's a Perl script that's probably a bit out of date.

I haven't used it so I can't say how well it performs with modern C++, but at least it can provide a starting point for creating a modern tool.

Comment: "but is also commenting on things I don't care anything about at this point but is also commenting on things I don't care anything about at this point" -- I hope you realise those notes you get are specifically about the concrete error in your code. I do get that they're hard to read, but your question gives the impression that they're unrelated to the error.

Comment: @hvd  Yes, maybe I wasn't clear.  My students are beginning C and C++ programmers and they won't be exposed to things like overloading, classes, templates, and the like until much later in the course, or in some cases not until follow-on courses.  For that reason I see no reason to confuse them any more than necessary with messages that contains such concepts.  All they they need to know early on is that there is something wrong with one of their operands, not all the possible options for that operand.

Comment: @cheers-and-hth-alf [Stlfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) doesn't seem to exist anymore.